# Java arrayList empty after going over a socket

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I've been working on a chat application using a java.io socket.

Context : A client sends a Message object encapsulated in a Packet object over a socket. Once the server retrieves the Packet, it broadcast an Arraylist containing all Message to a client.

My problem is that on the server side (before sending over the socket), the payload of the packet is as intended (an Arraylist with messages the client send), and when receive by a client (after the socket), the Arraylist of messages is empty (the debugger tells me that the arraylist has a size = 0 and I can't retrieve any message). I didn't find anything online about this and the debugger didn't help me much.

Here is the code used (The packet class containts command specifying if it's To Client (TC) or From Client(FC)) :

Client side :

```
public void run(){
    try {
        while(true){
            packet = (Packet) streamFromServer.readObject();
            switch (packet.command){
                case TCGETMSG:
                    messageGlobalStorage = (ArrayList<Message>)packet.payload;
                    break;
                case TCGETUSERS:
                    usersOnline = (DefaultListModel<User>) packet.payload;
                    break;
                case TCGETSTATS:
                    System.out.println("Getting stats");
                    break;
                default:
                    //Add undefined packet handling
                    break;
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
public boolean sendMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        streamToServer.writeObject(new Packet(Packet.Commands.FCSENDMSG, message));
        return true;
    }catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Server side :

```
private void threadRoutine() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    try {
        //Receiving from the client => Inverse logic : SENDMSG = retreive message; 
        //GETMSG = broadcast message to client
        while (true){
            Packet packet = (Packet) din.readObject();
            switch (packet.command){
                case FCSENDMSG:
                    server.messageGlobalStorage.add((Message) packet.payload);
                    server.broadcast((Message) packet.payload);
                    break;
                case FCGETMSG:
                    Packet temp = new Packet(Packet.Commands.TCGETMSG, server.messageGlobalStorage);
                    dout.writeObject(temp);
                    break;
                case FCGETUSERS:
                    dout.writeObject(new Packet(Packet.Commands.TCGETUSERS, server.userOnlineMap.keySet()));
                    break;
                case FCGETSTATS:
                    //Add Stats handling
                    break;
                default:
                    //Add undefined packet handling
                    break;
           }
      }
    }finally {
        server.removeConnection(socket);
        System.out.println("Removing connection");
    }
}
```

```
void broadcast() throws IOException{
    for (ObjectOutputStream dout : userOnlineMap.values()){
        dout.writeObject(new Packet(Packet.Commands.TCGETMSG, messageGlobalStorage));
    }
}
```

If the code of the Packet / Message class is needed, tell me I'll add it to this post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can modify the broadcast method to use a single ObjectOutputStream instance to write to the socket instead of using separate instances for each client. By creating the Packet object outside of the loop and using a single dout instance to write to the socket, you can ensure that all clients receive the updated messageGlobalStorage list.
Could you try this?

```
void broadcast() throws IOException {
    Packet packet = new Packet(Packet.Commands.TCGETMSG,messageGlobalStorage);
    for (ObjectOutputStream dout : userOnlineMap.values()) {
        dout.writeObject(packet);
        dout.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't change anything, the size of the receive array on client side is still 0. I checked my Message class, my packet class and all are Serializable. I wonder if an Arraylist of custom object can behave strangely when it is serialize.

Comment: you're answer was partially correct, the reference to the messageGlobalStorage needed to be updated with dout.rese()t, I just needed to do it before writing to the ObjectOuputStream.